# How to enable c++11 support for Atmel Studio?

Tags: avr, c++, atmel-studio

I am currently using Atmel Studio 7 and I need to enable c++11 support for it. I couldn't find any documentation about this topic. Moreover, I am not even sure it has c++11 support, yet.

Comment: Have never tried it but does it work if you go into the AVR/GNU C Compiler / Miscellaneous options for the project and change `-std=gnu99` to `-std=gnu++11`?

Comment: An alternative I am using is setting the compiler flag `-std=c++11`. You can write this or PeterJs solution in the "Other flags field of Miscelleaneous of AVR/GNU C++ Compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just started a new C++ project under Atmel Studio 7 and with the default options the following code failed with a `nullptr` not declared error:

```
char *c;
if (c == nullptr)
    ;
```

Then I went into the Toolchain options under the project properties and added the `-std=c++11` flag as suggested by Grebu under the "other flags" which seemed like the best place for it and it compiled fine:

[image: Atmel Studio with C++ 11 enabled]